# Bluetooth connection is getting disconnected adruptly in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

When i am trying to pair device with Samsung galaxy Xcover 5 (SMG525F) , we are getting abruptly disconnected, following are the BT stack logs which are getting printed before disconnection

```
06-07 19:15:41.363  1225  1886 I bt_stack: [INFO:btsnoop.cc(544)] clear_l2cap_whitelist: Clearing whitelist from l2cap channel. conn_handle=352 cid=64:138
06-07 19:15:41.363  1225  1886 I bt_stack: [INFO:port_rfc.cc(1004)] port_rfc_closed: RFCOMM connection closed, index=10, state=2, reason=Peer connection failed[16], UUID=0x1101, bd_addr=84253f, is_server=0
06-07 19:15:41.363  1225  1919 E bt_btif_sock_rfcomm: find_rfc_slot_by_id unable to find RFCOMM slot id: 45
06-07 19:15:41.364  1225  1886 E bt_btm  : Reset sec_bd_name and name flag. (BR/EDR link)
06-07 19:15:41.368 16532  7817 V Bluetooth: We are in the wait for InStream data
06-07 19:15:41.370  1225  1886 W bt_btif : BtifAvPeer *BtifAvSource::FindOrCreatePeer(const RawAddress &, tBTA_AV_HNDL, uint32_t): Create peer: peer_address=84253f bta_handle=0x41 peer_id=0
06-07 19:15:41.370  1225  1886 W bt_btif : virtual bool BtifAvStateMachine::StateIdle::ProcessEvent(uint32_t, void *): Peer 84253f : event=BTIF_AV_ACL_DISCONNECTED(0x23)
06-07 19:15:41.371  1225  1886 W bt_btif : DeleteIdlePeers: Deleting idle peer: 84253f bta_handle=0x41
06-07 19:15:41.378   916  1457 D SLocation: BluetoothStatusMonitor - sgfm received : android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
06-07 19:15:41.378  1225  1399 D BluetoothUtils: getBtEnabledContainers(): btContainers = []
06-07 19:15:41.378  1225  1399 E BluetoothRemoteDevices: setAclConnected :: connected = false, mSocketConnectedCount = 0
06-07 19:15:41.378  1225  1399 D BluetoothDataManager: BluetoothDataManager :: notifyDisconnectReason() is called!!!
06-07 19:15:41.378  1225  1399 W bt_btif : BTA_DM_BUSY_LEVEL_EVT :: p_data->busy_level.level_flags : 0x0, spen_connected : 0 0
06-07 19:15:41.378  1225  1225 D BluetoothAdapterService: getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@798d0f9
06-07 19:15:41.379  1245  1419 V BluetoothEventManager: onReceive :: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
06-07 19:15:41.382  1225  1225 I SapService: Unexpected error!
06-07 19:15:41.382  1225  1225 D BluetoothPbapService: action: android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
06-07 19:15:41.382  1245  1419 D BluetoothController: updateConnected = 0mConnectionState = 0
06-07 19:15:41.383 11565 11565 I [+5]oneconnect[1.7.65.43_01][CORE]: BTStateChangeReceiver.onReceive - Action : android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED
06-07 19:15:41.384 11565 11565 I [+5]oneconnect[1.7.65.43_01][CORE]: BluetoothHelper.handleActionConnectionStateChanged -  [action]android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED [connState]0[address] - ($)
06-07 19:15:41.387 11565 11565 I [+5]oneconnect[1.7.65.43_01][CORE]: BluetoothHelper.handleActionConnectionStateChanged - S**********
06-07 19:15:41.388   916  1391 I SpenGestureManagerService: getBleSpenAddress
06-07 19:15:41.388   916  1391 E BleSpenManager: getBleSpenAddress : BLE Spen is not supported
06-07 19:15:41.387  1225  1399 D BluetoothUtils: getBtEnabledContainers(): btContainers = []
06-07 19:15:41.388  1225  1399 E BluetoothRemoteDevices: Remote class is UNCATEGORIZED
```